# Minha página não preenche totalmente a janela em mobile. Por que?

Tags: html, css

Mesmo com o `width 100%` nas tags de estrutura quando faço o teste em mobile a página não preenche totalmente:
[image: ![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por que isso acontece?

```css
* {margin: 0 auto; padding: 0 auto;}

/*
    Por a largura se repetir 
    utilizei a classe default-structure-formatting 
    para a definir e evitar repetições. 
    Os atributos específicos de altura e cor estão em cada respectiva tag.
*/

.default-structure-formatting
{
    width: 100%;    
}

header 
{
    background-color: #000;
    height: 120px;
}

nav 
{
    background-color: #09f;
    height: 30px;
}

section 
{
    background-color: #891e2b;
    height: 600px;
}

footer 
{
    background-color: #000;
    height: 30px;
}


/* Formatação de Texto*/
.default-text-formatting {text-align: center; color: white; }

.default-content-formatting {width: 994px;color: white; padding: 100px auto;}

header h1 {padding: 40px 0;}
nav h3 {padding: 5px 0;}
article p {padding: 220px 0; text-align: justify;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/style.css">
    <title>Atividade II</title>
</head>

<body>
        <header class="default-structure-formatting "> <h1 class="default-text-formatting">LOGO</h1></header>    
        
        <nav class="default-structure-formatting "> 
            <h3 class="default-text-formatting">HOME - PORTFOLIO - SOBRE - CONTATO</h3>
        </nav>
        
        <section class="default-structure-formatting ">
            <article > <p class="default-content-formatting"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste quos temporibus debitis quam magni. Recusandae sequi incidunt, corporis asperiores dolores nulla, facilis perferendis, enim rerum esse labore vero tempore distinctio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro iure placeat, distinctio esse dicta a quidem? Magnam, itaque repellat, laudantium inventore est corrupti voluptate aut recusandae tempore autem dicta esse. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam illo officia voluptates veritatis sequi iure, vero eos, a repudiandae consectetur qui ea rem. Voluptatum aliquid quam beatae unde reiciendis ducimus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi in ut hic commodi deserunt expedita voluptatem amet aperiam molestiae nobis laborum, odit optio distinctio impedit voluptas, dolor ratione, labore explicabo. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam expedita quidem mollitia itaque animi porro error quas sequi autem enim quae quia voluptate consequatur atque ratione suscipit, temporibus possimus vero. </p> </article>
        </section>
        
        <footer class="default-structure-formatting default-text-formatting"> Site © 2020 </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como a resposta do Thiago citou, ao especificar um `width` fixo na div de `994px`, se a tela for menor que isso, a div continuará com os mesmos `994px` de largura, criando esse espaço vazio na lateral direita. Se quer que essa div tenha no máximo `994px` de largura, troque o `width` por `max-width`.

Agora, há outro erro no seu código neste `padding: 100px auto;`. O `padding` não aceita valor `auto`, como você pode ver neste print ao inspecionar o elemento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste trecho também você fez a mesma coisa:

```
* {margin: 0 auto; padding: 0 auto;}
```

Se não quiser `padding` nas laterais, troque o `auto` por `0` em:

```
.default-content-formatting {
   max-width: 994px;color: white; padding: 100px 0;
}
```

E aqui basta deixar apenas o `0`:

```
* {margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá @luan isso esta ocorrendo por causa do `width: 994px;` que você deu na classe **.default-content-formatting**, na minha solução eu alterei para `max-width: 994px;`, mas você pode criar uma **@media** para a parte do mobile

```css
* {margin: 0 auto; padding: 0 auto;}

/*
    Por a largura se repetir 
    utilizei a classe default-structure-formatting 
    para a definir e evitar repetições. 
    Os atributos específicos de altura e cor estão em cada respectiva tag.
*/

.default-structure-formatting
{
    width: 100%;    
}

header 
{
    background-color: #000;
    height: 120px;
}

nav 
{
    background-color: #09f;
    height: 30px;
}

section 
{
    background-color: #891e2b;
    height: 600px;
}

footer 
{
    background-color: #000;
    height: 30px;
}


/* Formatação de Texto*/
.default-text-formatting {text-align: center; color: white; }

.default-content-formatting {max-width: 994px;color: white; padding: 100px auto;}

header h1 {padding: 40px 0;}
nav h3 {padding: 5px 0;}
article p {padding: 220px 0; text-align: justify;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/style.css">
    <title>Atividade II</title>
</head>

<body>
        <header class="default-structure-formatting "> <h1 class="default-text-formatting">LOGO</h1></header>    
        
        <nav class="default-structure-formatting "> 
            <h3 class="default-text-formatting">HOME - PORTFOLIO - SOBRE - CONTATO</h3>
        </nav>
        
        <section class="default-structure-formatting ">
            <article > <p class="default-content-formatting"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste quos temporibus debitis quam magni. Recusandae sequi incidunt, corporis asperiores dolores nulla, facilis perferendis, enim rerum esse labore vero tempore distinctio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro iure placeat, distinctio esse dicta a quidem? Magnam, itaque repellat, laudantium inventore est corrupti voluptate aut recusandae tempore autem dicta esse. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam illo officia voluptates veritatis sequi iure, vero eos, a repudiandae consectetur qui ea rem. Voluptatum aliquid quam beatae unde reiciendis ducimus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi in ut hic commodi deserunt expedita voluptatem amet aperiam molestiae nobis laborum, odit optio distinctio impedit voluptas, dolor ratione, labore explicabo. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam expedita quidem mollitia itaque animi porro error quas sequi autem enim quae quia voluptate consequatur atque ratione suscipit, temporibus possimus vero. </p> </article>
        </section>
        
        <footer class="default-structure-formatting default-text-formatting"> Site © 2020 </footer>

</body>
</html>
```